# How do I put all column names in a php array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named ***showcase*** and I want the user inserting his products in this table. The point is that I would like that the user could add showcase argument like "sale" or whatever he wants. To do that I thought he could insert the showcase argument in a form and then add it like a column in the showcase table. ***If I don't know column names how can I show them***?

**EDIT**

Ok, I used this code, I skipped the first column because it's the id one... It doesn't show me nothing but the part after the foreach... Do you know what could it be?

```
<form method="post" action="move_showcase.php">
  <?php
    $result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vetrina");
    $element  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $value    = array(array_keys($element));
    $i        = 0;
      foreach($value as $rowname){

        if($i==0){
          $i++;
          continue;
        }
      ?>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input name="rowpost[]" type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
          </span>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="color:#d9534f; cursor:pointer;" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
            <?php
              echo $rowname;
            ?>
          </span>
        </div>
      <?php
      }
  ?>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkaddshcs">
        Altra Vetrina
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addrowname" placeholder="Aggiungi Vetrina">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </form>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM showcase`

Comment: Then use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the first item

Comment: The variable is an associative array with all the column names. Get them using PHP function.

Comment: You definitely do _not_ want to add columns for some user provided data. You use a reference table for such additional details.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy what php function?

Comment: `array_keys` function, the indexes will be store in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a query to show all the column names:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `vetrina`
```

You can loop the return value like normal table rows.

```
$ergebnis = mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `vetrina`');

while ( $array = mysql_fetch_array( $ergebnis ) ){
  $columns[] = $array['Field'];
}

// remove first name
$columns = array_slice( $columns, 1 );

foreach( $columns as $column ){
 echo $column;
 echo "\r\n";
}
```

---

I would recommend you to switch to PHP PDO or MySQLi, because php_mysql is outdated and insecure.

Also reading results is more powerful.

Comment: It doesn't work, It shows me id, int(11), NO that are id parameters